# Действия с элементами матрицы и ее диагональю

Tags: python, массивы, циклы, матрицы, numpy

Добрый день!

Вопрос: есть некий лист с элементами, например

```
      X = [0.1, 0.7 , 1, 1.35]
```

Нужно  создать  массив, где в каждой строке элемент по порядку добавляется ко всем остальным, причем чтобы сам этот элемент не учитывался ( первый добавляем ко второму,третьему...; второй к первому,третьему,... и т.д. . Если просто запустить цикл (использую numpy):

```
   import numpy as np

   X = map(np.array,[X])
   X = [0.1, 0.5 , 1, 1.5]
   X = ( X[:,None] + X[:] )

 #Результат
 [[ 0.2   0.8   1.1   1.45]
  [ 0.8   1.4   1.7   2.05]
  [ 1.1   1.7   2.    2.35]
  [ 1.45  2.05  2.35  2.7 ]]
```

но диагональные элементы нужно исключить, то есть результат должен быть:

```
   [[  0.8   1.1   1.45]
    [ 0.8    1.7   2.05]
    [ 1.1    1.7    2.35]
    [ 1.45   2.05   2.35 ]]
```

Подскажите, как реализовать такое? И еще как потом найти сумму каждой строки?

А если нужно прибавить другой лист, такого же размера (например

```
Y = [0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]

     (X[:,None] + X[:]) + (Y[:,None] + Y[:])
```

или

```
      X[:,None] + Y[:]
```

как изменить код в таком случае?

Comment: Как-то не очень хорошо понятна задача. Что с чем складывается? Приведите пример корректных входных данных и корректных ожидаемых выходных, желательно несколько более изощренных, чем `1 2 3 4 5`.

Comment: Что значит удалить диагональ? Вы можете привести искомый результат?

Comment: Правки ввел, результат добавил

Comment: В конце ввел еще одно условие, забыл упомянуть

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov, не совсем понятно к чему и что надо прибавить... `(X[:,None] + X[:]) + (Y[:,None] + Y[:])` - работает замечательно

Comment: Да, все работает, протестил)

Comment: Скажите ще пожалуйста: а возможно ли в numpy реализовать то, что предложил знаток Alban в следующем после вас комментарии?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov, если у вас возник новый вопрос то следует оформить его в качестве отдельного вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не уверен что до конца вас понял. Вот мое решение:

```
def f(array):
    new = [x+y for x in array for y in array if y!=x]
    return new

print(f([1, 2, 3]))
```

**Результат:**

```
[3, 4, 
3, 5,  
4, 5]
```

Делал без numpy. Но переделать будет не сложно.

**UPDATE:**

```
def for_stack(array):
    list_for_num_array = []
    for i in array:
        list_for_num_array.append([x+y for x in i for y in i if y!= x])
    return np.array(list_for_num_array)
X = np.array([[0.1, 0.7 , 1, 1.35]])
print(for_stack(X[:None]))
```

**Результат:**

```
[[ 0.8, 1.1, 1.45,
   0.8, 1.7, 2.05, 
   1.1, 1.7, 2.35, 
   1.45, 2.05, 2.35]]
```

Можно еще так:

```
foo = lambda array: ([j+n for i in array for x, j in enumerate(i) for y, n in enumerate(i) if x != y])
```

**Вариант с индексами:**

```
def for_stack(array):
    list_for_num_array = []
    for i in array:
        list_for_num_array.append([j+n for x, j in enumerate(i) for y, n in enumerate(i) if x != y])
    return np.array(list_for_num_array)
X = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2]])
print(for_stack(X[:None]))
```

**Результат:**

```
[[3 3 3 4 3 4],
 [3 3 3 4 3 4]]
```

**Еще один UPDATE:**

```
def for_stack(array):
    list_for_num_array = []
    try:
        for i, j in enumerate(array):
                list_for_num_array.append([x+n for x, n in zip(array[i], array[i+1])])
    except IndexError:
            pass
    return np.array(list_for_num_array)
X = np.array([[0.1, 0.7 , 1, 1.35], [2, 3, 4, 5]])
print(for_stack(X[:None]))
```

**Результат:**

```
[[ 2.1   3.7   5.    6.35]]
```

Складываем каждый X[n] + Y[n].

**UPD #3**

Автор задавал вопрос как удалить диагональ матрицы:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9]])
foo = lambda array: np.delete(array, np.diagonal(array-1))
```

**Результат:**

```
[[2 3 4 6 7 8]]
```

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть в numpy?

Comment: Александр, обновил ответ

Comment: Есть еще вопрос: а можно сделать так, чтобы условие if y!= x относилось не к самим объектам, а к индексам в массиве? то есть в первой строке первый элемент не считаем ( 0.1 + 0.1 не считаем),все остальные считаем по правилу x+y; во второй строке второй элемент не учитываем ( то есть 0.7 + 0.7 не считаем), в третьей строке - 1 + 1 и т.д. Просто если в лист добавить два одинаковых значения изначально - ответ будет не тот, что мне нужен).Короче цель : номер строки = номер элемента в строке, который не учитываем (первая строка - первый, вторая - второй и т.д.).

Comment: Александр, обновил ответ.

Comment: И последний вопрос по сабжу: как использовать вариант с индексами, если нужно прибавить элементы одного листа к другому ( например некий лист X и Y), например new = X [:] + Y [:]

Comment: Каким образом можно переделать метод с индексами под такой[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660313/python-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment951430_660313] случай?

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```
In [221]: X = np.array([0.1, 0.7 , 1, 1.35])

In [222]: l = len(X)

In [223]: A = np.delete(X[:,None] + X[:], np.arange(0, l**2, l+1)).reshape(l,l-1)

In [224]: A
Out[224]:
array([[ 0.8 ,  1.1 ,  1.45],
       [ 0.8 ,  1.7 ,  2.05],
       [ 1.1 ,  1.7 ,  2.35],
       [ 1.45,  2.05,  2.35]])
```

найти сумму каждой строки:

```
In [225]: A.sum(axis=1)
Out[225]: array([ 3.35,  4.55,  5.15,  5.85])
```

**Некоторые пояснения:**

[np.delete()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) удаляет элементы матрицы по указанным индексам. Причем по умолчанию `np.delete()` сначала преобразует матрицу в одномерный (flattened) массив и соответственно ожидает индексы для такого `1D` массива:

Например удаление второго элемента диагонали по индексу (1,1) (со значением `1.4`) - для "flattened" матрицы этот элемент имеет индекс `5`:

```
In [228]: np.delete(X[:,None] + X[:], 5)
Out[228]: array([ 0.2 ,  0.8 ,  1.1 ,  1.45,  0.8 ,  1.7 ,  2.05,  1.1 ,  1.7 ,  2.  ,  2.35,  1.45,  2.05,  2.35,  2.7 ])
```

`np.arange(0, l**2, l+1)` - вернет нам индексы диагональных элементов в одномерном "flattened" массиве (для квадратной матрицы):

```
In [229]: np.arange(0, l**2, l+1)
Out[229]: array([ 0,  5, 10, 15])
```

получится:

```
In [230]: np.delete(X[:,None] + X[:], np.arange(0, l**2, l+1))
Out[230]: array([ 0.8 ,  1.1 ,  1.45,  0.8 ,  1.7 ,  2.05,  1.1 ,  1.7 ,  2.35,  1.45,  2.05,  2.35])
```

дальше преобразуем к нужной `2D` матрице:

```
In [231]: np.delete(X[:,None] + X[:], np.arange(0, l**2, l+1)).reshape(l,l-1)
Out[231]:
array([[ 0.8 ,  1.1 ,  1.45],
       [ 0.8 ,  1.7 ,  2.05],
       [ 1.1 ,  1.7 ,  2.35],
       [ 1.45,  2.05,  2.35]])
```

Comment: Благодарю, все работает! Можете объяснить, то значаит  
        np.arange(0, l**2, l+1) ?