# Python :постановка условия в цикле с несколькими массивами

Tags: python, массивы, циклы, numpy

Есть код:

```
import math
import numpy as np
X = [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Y = [ 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
G = [ -0.5818708816896146, -0.17982884214560324, -1.3877787807814457e-17, 
     0.1798288421456033, 0.5818708816896146]
X, Y, G = map(np.array, [X, Y,G ])

# Подсчет скоростей
r22 = ((X[:] - X[:,None]) ** 2 + (Y[:] - Y[:,None]) ** 2)
Vx = (Y[:] - Y[:,None]) * G[:] / (2 * math.pi * r22)
Vy = (X[:] - X[:,None]) * G[:] / -(2 * math.pi * r22)
```

В результате получим:

```
#r22
  [[ 0.      0.0625  0.25    0.5625  1.    ]
   [ 0.0625  0.      0.0625  0.25    0.5625]
   [ 0.25    0.0625  0.      0.0625  0.25  ]
   [ 0.5625  0.25    0.0625  0.      0.0625]
   [ 1.      0.5625  0.25    0.0625  0.    ]]
  #Vx
    [[     nan -0.11448 -0.       0.03816  0.09261]
     [ 0.37043      nan -0.       0.05724  0.12348]
     [ 0.18522  0.11448      nan  0.11448  0.18522]
     [ 0.12348  0.05724  0.           nan  0.37043]
     [ 0.09261  0.03816  0.      -0.11448      nan]]
   #Vy
    [[ nan   0.   0.  -0.  -0.]
     [  0.  nan   0.  -0.  -0.]
     [  0.   0.  nan  -0.  -0.]
     [  0.   0.   0.  nan  -0.]
     [  0.   0.   0.  -0.  nan]]
```

Похожий вопрос был задан [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643368/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E?noredirect=1#comment916059_643368), но то был случай для одного листа X, здесь же листов несколько, а правильно задать условие, используя предыдущий ответ у меня не получилось.

Суть вопроса: каким правильно поставить условие в генераторе списков или в коде numpy, чтобы не было нулей в r22 и соответственно, деления на ноль в последующих Vx и Vy( если i - элемент листа X, а j - элемент листа Y, то если i = j  - вычитание не производить).

```
 #Нужный результат r22 
     [[ 0.0625  0.25    0.5625  1.    ]
      [ 0.0625  0.0625  0.25    0.5625]
      [ 0.25    0.0625  0.0625  0.25  ]
      [ 0.5625  0.25    0.0625  0.0625]
      [ 1.      0.5625  0.25    0.0625]]
   #Нужный результат Vx 
     [[ -0.11448 -0.     0.03816  0.09261]
      [ 0.37043  -0.     0.05724  0.12348]
      [ 0.18522  0.11448 0.11448  0.18522]
      [ 0.12348  0.05724  0.      0.37043]
      [ 0.09261  0.03816  0.     -0.11448]]
   #Нужный результат Vy 
    [[  0.   0.  -0.  -0.]
     [  0.   0.  -0.  -0.]
     [  0.   0.  -0.  -0.]
     [  0.   0.   0.  -0.]
     [  0.   0.   0.  -0.]]
```

Comment: Вы можете пояснить что вы считаете? И что такое `X`, `Y`, `G`?

Comment: X,Y - листы с координатами точек, G - некий коэффициент. Нужно посчитать по формулам значение скоростей в точках (Vx, Vy).